# Interface e herança em Xamarin - System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, web-service, xamarin, herança, interface

Saudações!

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Cross Plataform em Xamarin.
Este projeto consiste em consumir o método de um web-service que vai retornar o código do roteiro e um vetor de endereços que corresponde ao roteiro.

Mas o retorno do método RoteiroAtual me dá a seguinte exceção: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`.

Esse erro passou a ocorrer apenas depois que inclui toda estrutura necessária para o funcionamento da interface rota.

Sem a interface rota o problema não ocorre. Não consigo entender o motivo do erro de conversão que está ocorrendo. Onde estou errando?!
Toda definição de estrutura do código será descrita a seguir.

Dentro de meu portable tenho as interfaces:

```
    public interface IRoteiro<TRota> where TRota : IRota
    {

        int Codigo { get; set; }

        TRota[] Rotas { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IRota
    {

        string Endereco { get; set; }

        string URL { get; set; }

    }

    public interface ITransportadorSoapService
    {
        Task<IRoteiro<IRota>> RoteiroAtual(int codigoTransportador);
    }
```

Já dentro da plataforma tenho as classes:

```
    public partial class Roteiro : IRoteiro<Rota>
    {
     
    }

    public partial class Rota : IRota
    {

    }

    public sealed class TransportadorSoapService : ITransportadorSoapService
    {

        public TransportadorSoapService()
        {

        }

        public async Task<IRoteiro<IRota>> RoteiroAtual(int codigoTransportador)
        {

            //Webservice referenciado na plataforma
            WSRoteiro.RT ws = new WSRoteiro.RT
            {
                Timeout = 60000
            };

            //Este return dispara a exceção.
            return (IRoteiro<IRota>)await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return ws.RoteiroTransportador(codigoTransportador);
            });

        }

    }
```

Dentro do portable tenho uma page com um método que consome o método RoteiroAtual:

```
        private async void Inicializar()
        {

            try
            {
                var rotaAtual = await App.TransportadorSoapService.RoteiroAtual(transportadorLogado.Codigo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exceção disparada pelo return do método RoteiroAtual vem para este catch.
            }

        }
```

Abaixo está o formato do web-service consumido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde exatamente ocorre o erro? Parece ser um problema onde você acha que está atribuindo um tipo A para uma instância A, mas na verdade está tentando atribuir B em uma instância A.

Comment: Leandro. Acho que é algo neste sentido mesmo. Mas não estou conseguindo identificar isso no código acima. O local que dispara o erro é o return do método RoteiroAtual que está com um comentário acima da linha de execução dele.

Comment: Você consegue debugar o código?

Comment: Sim. Consigo debugar o código.
Este é o trecho de código que dispara a exceção:

return (IRoteiro<IRota>)await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return ws.RoteiroTransportador(codigoTransportador);
            });

O problema é que preciso retornar um IRoteiro<IRota> e é isso que gera a exceção.

Mas se eu armazenar o retorno de ws.RoteiroTransportador(codigoTransportador) da forma abaixo sem tentar a conversão eu obtenho a informação de retorno:

var rt = ws.RoteiroTransportador(codigoTransportador);

Somente tentando a conversão no return é que tenho a exceção.